Imágenes infinitas en opencv2 python
Estoy tratando de hacer un programa que siga tu ratón y dibuje el circulo en él.
Es solo un experimento; pero al momento en el que aparezca la imagen, se clonan múltiples imágenes en una sola ventana.
Este es el código:
import cv2 as cv
import pyautogui
import time
import numpy as np

time.sleep(0.5)

def screenshot():

    global color_cap

    vieja_cap=pyautogui.screenshot()
    color_cap=cv.cvtColor(np.array(vieja_cap).astype("uint8"), cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    mouse_x, mouse_y=pyautogui.position()
    print("x={}, y={}".format(mouse_x, mouse_y))
    cv.circle(color_cap, (mouse_x+3, mouse_y+3), 10, (0,255,0), 3)
    color_cap=cv.resize(color_cap, (0,0), fx=0.6, fy=0.6)
    cv.imshow("Prueba", color_cap)

def main_loop():

    while True:

        screenshot()

        if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
            break

main_loop()

El problema que ocurre es esto:

Y por más cosas que intente no encuentro una solución.

Lo que pasa es que estás capturando screenshots cada vez, por eso se genera ese efecto. Es parecido a cuando se colocan dos espejos mirándose uno al otro, o cuando grabas una imagen que se proyecta en una pantalla.

Y cómo podría resolverlo??
